# Jenkins Gitlab Localhost - Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h

Tags: jenkins, localhost, gitlab, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-github-plugin

I am trying to connect Jenkins with GitLab, both are installed on the same Unix server, in Jenkins Manager System the connection is successful. But in Job when I put the URL in the Repository URL it gives an error message:
"Failed to connect to repository: Command" git ls-remote -h "

We are trying via http: // localhost, but we have already tried to use the domain https://git.MYCLIENT.org.br/REPOSITORY.git, we also have SSH, we use PRIVATE KEY SSH, we use ACCESS TOKEN from GIT, we have done all settings to do. Even so, continue with this mistake!

Comment: Your user Git for Jenkins was added to your repository, right?

Comment: Yes, I did it. I create an user Jenkins into my repository.